# Unknown column while using EXTRACTVALUE

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1054, extract-value

I have this XML:

```
<List>
    <Attribute>
        <Id>NAME</Id>
        <Value>JOHN</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Id>CITY</Id>
        <Value>NEW YORK</Value>
    </Attribute>
</List>
```

Below is query:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xml, "List/Attribute[Id[text()='NAME']]/Value")
FROM xx;
```

But getting error as

> Unknown column 'List/Attribute[Id[text()='NAME']]/Value' in 'field list'.

I want to retrieve the value of NAME which should return as JOHN

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure you copied the query correctly?

Comment: You would get this error if you use backticks instead of double quotes around the Xpath expression.